# paypal express checkout without server integration

Tags: javascript, paypal

I follow this documentation and has done with below code.

```
paypal.Button.render({

      env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

      client: {
          sandbox: 'xxxxxxxxx',
          production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
      },

      payment: function() {

          var env    = this.props.env;
          var client = this.props.client;

          return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
              transactions: [
                  {
                      amount: { total: ($scope.qty * 19) + '.00' , currency: 'USD' },
                      item_list: {
                      items: [{
                          "name": "bag",
                          "quantity": $scope.qty,
                          "price": "19.00",
                          "currency": "USD"
                        }]
                    }
                  }
              ]
          });
      },

      commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

      onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

          // Optional: display a confirmation page here

          return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
              // Show a success page to the buyer
              console.log(data);
              //save data to db

          });
      }

  }, '#paypal-button');
```

Is that all? What I should do next with paypal? I know I'm going to post something to my server if the `1actions.payment.execute()` is not fail. But if that is all, what does the node.js sdk of paypal for? I'm confused now. I tried to pay using test account, but the balance did not get deducted, hmm..

Comment: `actions.payment.execute()` should finalize the transaction and send the money. Are you sure you don't see it in your account? sometimes it takes a short while to appear. Alternatively, do you see any console errors?

Comment: @bluepnume no error in the console. If that is sufficient what's the paypal fo node.js npm for? What's the access token for?

Comment: I have the same issue. did you manage to resolve it. I dont get any error in console also

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for, but it took a while before I figured it out.

To read the information from the transaction you need to call actions.payment.get().

```
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
                 if(data.state === 'approved'){
                   console.log(data);
                   console.log(data.id);
                   // Update orderstatus in backend    
                 }else{
                  console.log(data);
                 }
               });
          });
```